# object based file system vs hybrid storage(file system & Object storage) , what're their differences?

Tags: ceph

IN this article "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_storage" ,

It says Lustre is a object based file system and says ceph is a hybrid storage.

I really don't know their differences.  ceph also is a distributed file system , block storage , object storage.  Anyone know of that ,  Ceph 's  file system and block storage is based object store or not ?

Answer (score 1):

The content of a file stored on the [Ceph file system](http://ceph.com/docs/hammer/cephfs/) which provides a POSIX API can be retrieved via the [librados API](http://docs.ceph.com/docs/hammer/rados/api/librados/) which is an Object Store API similar to [SWIFT](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/swift/) or [S3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_S3). Although this is why [Ceph](http://ceph.com) deserves to be called a UFOS (Unified File and Object Storage) or *hybrid storage*, it is not a supported use case.

If the Ceph file system implementation changes to modify the names of the objects used to store the content of the files, the user of the librados API will need to know about it and adapt.

An *hybrid storage* would allow the user to conveniently store an object named **foo** via the object store API and retrieve it under a similar name (for instance **/objectstore/foo**) via the POSIX API, without knowing the implementation details.

Comment: More clear explanation.  That is say ,   ceph is actually an object store system . Also is a file system because of could be accessing via posix api ?    In my head , File system could be used by computers in operation system levels ,  not like using app level storage through restfull api or other app level protocols.